# What's the best way to determine my service is done loading & processing a HTTP get request?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've got a service in Angular JS which basically performs a HTTP GET & some post-processing like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('graphDataService', function($http) {
    this.getGraphData() {
      $http.get('http://localhost:32105/chartData')
        .then(function(result) {
          // Perform post processing here   
        });
    };
  });
```

What's the best way to communicate with my controller that the GET request and post-processing is complete?  I've attempted creating a `this.doneLoading` variable within my service but I can't access it from the asynchronous code.

I'm still rather new at Angular so any suggestions or criticism would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get()` returns a promise which you then call `.then()` upon. I think the proper solution is to have the service return the promise rather than notify the caller.

[Here's more information on how these promises work](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

In case you need to do post-processing in your service you should create your own promise and return it like A.B showed in his example. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use promises and return a promise instead, or should use defer or resolve methods on it

using $q

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('graphDataService', function($http,$q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    this.getGraphData() {
      $http.get('http://localhost:32105/chartData')
        .success(function(result) {
           defer.resolve(result);
        });
    };
    return defer.promise;
  });
```

now you can use then() in controller

Comment: Exactly how I was planning to do it after Emil's answer.  I really appreciate the answer and example--I hope you don't mind me giving Emil the credit as he answered first.